# How to inject custom scope into QML/Javascript console

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2

I found [QML Book](http://qmlbook.github.io/) an incredible good resource for learning QML. I'm currently implementing their suggested [Javascript Console](http://qmlbook.github.io/en/ch14/index.html) into my QML application. However I'm struggling with applying the console into the scope of my application.

**excerpt from QML Book / Page 13 - Javascript**

```
// jsconsole.js
.pragma library

var scope = {
  // our custom scope injected into our function evaluation
  // <<--- How do I inject the "custom" scope? 
}

function call(msg) {
    var exp = msg.toString();
    console.log(exp)
    var data = {
        expression : msg
    }
    try {
        var fun = new Function('return (' + exp + ');');
        data.result = JSON.stringify(fun.call(scope), null, 2)
        console.log('scope: ' + JSON.stringify(scope, null, 2) + 'result: ' + result)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.toString())
        data.error = e.toString();
    }
    return data;
}
```

If this is a small QML app:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ListModel {
        id: contactsModel
        ListElement {
            name: "Bill Smith"
            position: "Engineer"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "John Brown"
            position: "Engineer"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Sam Wise"
            position: "Manager"
        }
    }

    ListView{
        id: contactsView
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.margins: 10
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        orientation: Qt.Vertical
        spacing: 10
        model: contactsModel
        delegate: Rectangle{
            width: 150
            height: 30
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 1
            Text{
                text: name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How could I inject for example root Component or the contactsModel as a custom scope?

I would appreciate if you could help me out!

Thanks!